# Passing data in angular, data binding with Input

Tags: angular

i have a question need some help in angular. I have header component which is used in every page. It containes page title as naming the page in every page and page subtitle only if there are some info to be shown. I have detail page with title and subtitle(here i have icon shown) and edit-page only with title. Would like to show icon based on whats on subtitle from detail-page. When i add icon on title in my page-header component then it appears in my detail-page tite which i dont like that, only to bi visible on edit page. Any advice, help? TIA

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please, check out: [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve yours.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.